# How can I find the type of RAM my Dell Inspiron R14 (5420) uses?

Tags: windows-8

I own a Dell Inspiron R14 (5420) laptop (i5 3rd gen). Currently, it has 4GB of RAM installed, but I would like to increase the RAM to 8GB. I don't know how to figure out what the specifications should be for the replacement RAM. How can I find out what type of RAM to purchase for my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling Inspiron 5420 ram will give you an answer pretty quickly.  Spec for the RAM is DDR3 PC3-12800, DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 (non-ECC) SODIMM  - and you will need 2 x 4 GIG sticks.  It might be an idea to have a look at what RAM is currently installed, so you know if you have 1 or 2 sticks and the speed - you may be able to save yourself the cost of 1 stick.  [ You should always try get identical memory though ]

One of the nice things about Dell is their service tags.  You can typically find this reference on the bottom of the notebook - plug it into their website and it will show you the details of the computer, normally including the RAM configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can look it up on [crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Inspiron%2014R%20%285420%29&Cat=RAM). It uses DDR3 PC3-12800/DDR3-1600 Unbuffered NON-ECC RAM - you don't have to buy it from them.